# How to get a different context-menu showing on a TreeViewers header

Tags: eclipse-rcp, jface

I wish to let users toggle column's visibility in a TreeViewer. I already have a context menu bound to the right-click of my TreeViewer using ..

```
MenuManager.addMenuListener( new IMenuListener() ... );
```

.. but I can find no way of detecting when the right click is on the *header* of the table, rather than on the currently selected node. Down at the SWT level this is all possible, as is demonstrated by this snippet: http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet312.java The JFace layer however may not expose it as far as I can see.

Your clues and other musings are most welcome

M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I wrote this class to listen to the underlying tree object, and tell me when the column headers had been clicked on ...

```
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer;

public class HeaderClickDetector implements Listener
{
    TreeViewer viewer;
    private boolean headerClicked;

    public HeaderClickDetector( TreeViewer viewer )
    {
        this.viewer = viewer;
    }

    public void handleEvent(Event event)
    {
        Point pt = Display.getCurrent().map(null, viewer.getControl(), new Point(event.x, event.y));
        Rectangle clientArea = viewer.getTree().getClientArea();
        headerClicked = (clientArea.y <= pt.y && pt.y < (clientArea.y + viewer.getTree().getHeaderHeight()));       
    }

    public boolean isHeaderClicked()
    {
        return headerClicked;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your example, it helped alot. Since I actually needed to know *which* column header was clicked, I built upon your code and came to the following solution (which also works in case the original column ordering was changed by dragging):

```java
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MenuDetectEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MenuDetectListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree;

public class TreeColumnHeaderMenuDetectListener implements MenuDetectListener {
    private Tree fTree;
    private TreeViewer fTreeViewer;

    public TreeColumnHeaderMenuDetectListener(TreeViewer treeViewer)
    {
        fTree = treeViewer.getTree();
        fTreeViewer = treeViewer;
    }

    @Override
    public void menuDetected(MenuDetectEvent event) {
        Point curLoc = Display.getCurrent().map(null, fTreeViewer.getControl(), new Point(event.x, event.y));
        Rectangle clientArea = fTree.getClientArea();

        if (clientArea.y <= curLoc.y && curLoc.y < (clientArea.y + fTree.getHeaderHeight()) &&
            clientArea.x <= curLoc.x && curLoc.x < (clientArea.x + clientArea.width)) {
            int xOffset = 0;    // Accumulates previous column widths
            for (int colIdx : fTree.getColumnOrder()) {
                int colWidth = fTree.getColumn(colIdx).getWidth();
                // Check if cursor location lies within the current column
                if (xOffset <= curLoc.x && curLoc.x < (xOffset + colWidth)) {
                    System.out.println("column header "+colIdx);    // Your code goes here
                    break;
                }
                xOffset += colWidth;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use it by registering with

```
tree.addMenuDetectListener(new TreeColumnHeaderMenuDetectListener(treeViewer))
```

for a given tree and corresponding treeViewer.